# Нужна помощь в отладке метода сортировки массива

Tags: java, android

Делаю аналог bubble breaker,если оставить код таким как ниже,то можно протестировать и увидеть что все работает правильно,но,если раскомментировать вызов метода sdvig() в методе print(),станет видно что иногда при "уничтожении" соседних одноцветных ячеек уходит ещё несколько "лишних",подскажите в чем проблема

Сам метод (находит ячейки с 0 и сдвигает их вверх)

```
 private void sdvig(){
    for (int q=0;q<6;q++) {
        for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 6; j > 0; j--) {
                if (inColor[j][i] == 0) {
                    int temp = inColor[j][i];
                    inColor[j][i] = inColor[j - 1][i];
                    inColor[j - 1][i] = temp;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"   
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button21"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button22"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button23"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button24"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button25"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button26"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button31"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button32"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button33"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button34"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button35"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button36"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button41"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button42"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button43"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button44"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button45"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button46"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button51"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button52"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button53"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button54"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button55"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button56"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button61"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button62"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button63"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button64"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button65"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button66"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
</TableRow>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="новая игра"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="newGame" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="сдвиг"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="sdvig" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button b11;
private Button b12;
private Button b13;
private Button b14;
private Button b15;
private Button b16;

private Button b21;
private Button b22;
private Button b23;
private Button b24;
private Button b25;
private Button b26;

private Button b31;
private Button b32;
private Button b33;
private Button b34;
private Button b35;
private Button b36;

private Button b41;
private Button b42;
private Button b43;
private Button b44;
private Button b45;
private Button b46;

private Button b51;
private Button b52;
private Button b53;
private Button b54;
private Button b55;
private Button b56;

private Button b61;
private Button b62;
private Button b63;
private Button b64;
private Button b65;
private Button b66;

Random random = new Random();
private Button[][] buttons = new Button[8][8];
private int[][]inColor=new int[8][8];
int colors[] = { Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            inColor[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <7; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
            int pos = random.nextInt(colors.length);
            buttons[i][j].setBackgroundColor(colors[pos]);
            inColor[i][j]=colors[pos];
            Button button = buttons[i][j];
            button.setOnClickListener(listener);

        }
    }

}
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View myView) {

            Button clickedButton = (Button) myView;
            for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
                    if (clickedButton==buttons[i][j]){
                        Log.d("oolo", "Color " + inColor[i][j] + " " + i + j);
                        serch(i, j,inColor[i][j]);


                    }

                }
            }





    }
};
//метод находит ячейки с 0 и сдвигает их вверх
private void sdvig(){
    for (int q=0;q<6;q++) {
        for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 6; j > 0; j--) {
                if (inColor[j][i] == 0) {
                    int temp = inColor[j][i];
                    inColor[j][i] = inColor[j - 1][i];
                    inColor[j - 1][i] = temp;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    //вывод массива в лог
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
            System.out.print("     "+inColor[i][j]+"                  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        }

}
//метод поиска принимает координаты нажатой кнопки и цвет из её ячейки маасива,в случае нахождения совпадения с соседними присваивает им 0
private void serch(int x,int y,int cik) {
    if (cik != 0) {

        if (x > 0 & x < 7) {
            if (y > 0 & y < 7) {
                if (inColor[x - 1][y] == cik) {
                    Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x - 1][y]);
                    Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
                    inColor[x][y] = 0;
                    inColor[x - 1][y] = 0;
                    serch(x - 1, y, cik);


                }
                if (inColor[x + 1][y] == cik) {

                    Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x + 1][y]);
                    Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
                    inColor[x][y] = 0;
                    inColor[x + 1][y] = 0;
                    serch(x + 1, y, cik);


                }
                if (inColor[x][y - 1] == cik) {

                    Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y - 1]);
                    Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
                    inColor[x][y] = 0;
                    inColor[x][y - 1] = 0;
                    serch(x, y - 1, cik);


                }
                if (inColor[x][y + 1] == cik) {

                    Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y + 1]);
                    Log.d("oolo", "ravni " + inColor[x][y]);
                    inColor[x][y] = 0;
                    inColor[x][y + 1] = 0;
                    serch(x, y + 1, cik);


                }

            }
        }


    }
    print();
}
//метод отрисовывает цвет кнопкам
private void print(){
    //sdvig();
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
            buttons[i][j].setBackgroundColor(inColor[i][j]);
        }
    }

}
private void initArray() {
    b11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
    buttons[1][1] = b11;
    b12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
    buttons[1][2] = b12;
    b13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
    buttons[1][3] = b13;
    b14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
    buttons[1][4] = b14;
    b15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15);
    buttons[1][5] = b15;
    b16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button16);
    buttons[1][6] = b16;

    b21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);
    buttons[2][1] = b21;
    b22 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button22);
    buttons[2][2] = b22;
    b23 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button23);
    buttons[2][3] = b23;
    b24 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button24);
    buttons[2][4] = b24;
    b25 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button25);
    buttons[2][5] = b25;
    b26 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button26);
    buttons[2][6] = b26;

    b31 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button31);
    buttons[3][1] = b31;
    b32 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button32);
    buttons[3][2] = b32;
    b33 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button33);
    buttons[3][3] = b33;
    b34 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button34);
    buttons[3][4] = b34;
    b35 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button35);
    buttons[3][5] = b35;
    b36 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button36);
    buttons[3][6] = b36;

    b41 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button41);
    buttons[4][1] = b41;
    b42 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button42);
    buttons[4][2] = b42;
    b43 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button43);
    buttons[4][3] = b43;
    b44 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button44);
    buttons[4][4] = b44;
    b45 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button45);
    buttons[4][5] = b45;
    b46 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button46);
    buttons[4][6] = b46;

    b51 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button51);
    buttons[5][1] = b51;
    b52 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button52);
    buttons[5][2] = b52;
    b53 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button53);
    buttons[5][3] = b53;
    b54 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button54);
    buttons[5][4] = b54;
    b55 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button55);
    buttons[5][5] = b55;
    b56 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button56);
    buttons[5][6] = b56;

    b61 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button61);
    buttons[6][1] = b61;
    b62 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button62);
    buttons[6][2] = b62;
    b63 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button63);
    buttons[6][3] = b63;
    b64 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button64);
    buttons[6][4] = b64;
    b65 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button65);
    buttons[6][5] = b65;
    b66 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button66);
    buttons[6][6] = b66;
}

public void newGame(View view) {
    initArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            inColor[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <7; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
            int pos = random.nextInt(colors.length);
            buttons[i][j].setBackgroundColor(colors[pos]);
            inColor[i][j]=colors[pos];
            Button button = buttons[i][j];
            button.setOnClickListener(listener);

        }
    }
}

public void sdvig(View view) {
    sdvig();
    print();
}
}
```

Comment: я сомневаюсь ,что тут есть желающие разглядывать простыню вашего кода.

Comment: Вот это да, больше Button-ов богу Button-ов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе print() вы сделали переопределение метода sdvig(View view) в который, запихнули метод print(), в котором срабатывал sdvig(), здесь и ошибка. Чтоб код работал правильно, нужно раскомментировать здесь:

```
private void print(){
//sdvig(); //<- здесь
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
        buttons[i][j].setBackgroundColor(inColor[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

и удалить дублирование здесь:

```
public void sdvig(View view) {
sdvig();
print(); //<- Это удалить
}
```

метод сдвига захватывал "0" из 0x строчек массива,то есть верхней "граничной" которая не используется для удобства проверки соседних,исправил в sdvig() -

> for (int j = 6; j > 1; j--)

чтобы не сравнивал 1x с 0x строкой

Это самый быстрый способ, а по хорошему здесь начиная с разметки всё можно переписать. Удачи.

Comment: Делаю аналог bubble breaker,если оставить код таким как ниже,то можно протестировать и увидеть что все работает правильно,**но,если раскомментировать вызов метода sdvig() в методе print(),станет видно что иногда при "уничтожении" соседних одноцветных ячеек уходит ещё несколько "лишних"**,подскажите в чем проблема

Comment: удалите print(); в самом конце, в этом и проблема.

Comment: public void sdvig(View view) - я сделал только для проверки,и чтобы показать что в таком виде работает правильно,это кнопка которая вызывает сдвиг и отрисовку,она на деле и не нужна,проблема в том что если раскомментировать sdvig() в print(),он будет "автоматически" сдвигать как и задумывалось, но станет видно что иногда при "уничтожении" соседних одноцветных ячеек уходит ещё несколько "лишних".

Comment: те проблема не в этом? сейчас попробую скопировать код, если уж на то пошло и добавлю ответ.

Comment: Нашел,проблема была в том что метод сдвига захватывал "0" из 0x строчек массива,то есть верхней "граничной" которая не используется для удобства проверки соседних,исправил в sdvig() -  for (int j = 6; j > 1; j--) чтобы не сравнивал 1x с 0x строкой,и все заработало,спасибо всем

Comment: я не успел найти. Максим, используйте метод "заливки" в 10 раз сократит ваш код и увеличит производительность. Удачи.